# Weird web page issue in iE8... Possibly javascript

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have the following web page that is distorted in IE, but which validates and I can't find any problem with... [Here's a link to the page](https://www.inside-guides.co.uk/AdvertiserAdmin/ForgotPassword.asp) which looks fine in FF, Safari, chrome, but is not right in IE8.

I'm also getting this error in Chrome: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'focus' of null (anonymous function) onload".

Any suggestions would be great - the code, is as follows and the include files used appear on other pages, causing no problems at all:

```
<!--#include virtual="/System/Startup_FranchiseClient.asp"-->
<%
EnsurePageIsHTTPS

Dim blnShowResults : blnShowResults = False
Dim SQLCommand
Dim objConn
Dim rsUser
Dim rsEmail
Dim strTempPassword
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rsUser = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
Set rsEmail = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
Dim strPassword_Encrypted
Dim objEncrypt : Set objEncrypt = New Encrypt_MD5

If Request.Form("ForgotPassword") = "1" then
    SQLCommand = "SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE EmailAddress = '" & CleanSQLText(Request.Form("strUsername")) & "'"
    objConn.Open strConn
    rsUser.Open SQLCommand, objConn, adOpenKeySet, adLockOptimistic
    if rsUser.RecordCount <> 1 then
        strSecurity_LoginError = "Sorry, your details could not be found.  Please check your email address and try again.<br>"
    Else
        strTempPassword = NewGUID()
        strTempPassword = Mid(strTempPassword, 2, 8)
        strPassword_Encrypted = objEncrypt.EncryptMD5(strTempPassword)
        rsUser("ResetPasswordOnNextLogin") = True
        rsUser("Password") = strPassword_Encrypted
        rsUser.Update
        blnShowResults = True
        SQLCommand = "SELECT '" & CleanSQLText(strTempPassword) & "' AS NewPassword, EmailAddress FROM uvw_EmailContent_ForgotPassword WHERE EmailAddress = '" & CleanSQLText(Request.Form("strUsername")) & "'"
        rsEmail.Open SQLCommand, objConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
        SendPublicFranchiseEmailTemplate GetSiteConfig("Public_AutoEmailsFrom"), rsEmail("EmailAddress"), "Inside Guides Password Assistance", "EmailTemplate_ForgotPassword", True, rsEmail
        blnShowResults = True
    End if
    rsUser.Close
    Set rsUser = Nothing
End if
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Inside-Guides.co.uk - Advertiser Admin</title>
<!--#include virtual="/Assets/Templates/Public/Franchise/HeadCSS.asp"-->
</head>
<body class="advertisers" onload="javascript:document.getElementById('strUsername').focus();">
<!--#include virtual="/Assets/Templates/Public/Franchise/TemplateStartPages.asp"-->
<h1>Forgot Password</h1>
<%
If blnShowResults = False then
    %>
    <div class="bg MainCopy">
     <p>Please enter your email address below and we will email you your password:</p><br />
    <p class="ErrorText"><% = strSecurity_LoginError %></p>  
    <form name="LoginForm" method="post" action="ForgotPassword.asp">
      <input type="hidden" name="ForgotPassword" value="1" />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th align="left" valign="middle" style="width:110px;">
                    Email Address:
                </th>
                <td align="left" valign="middle">
                    <input type="text" name="strUsername" value="" />
                </td>
                <td align="right" valign="middle">
                    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Send Password" />
                </td>
                </tr>
          </table>
    </form>
</div>
    <%
Else
    %>
    <%
    If Session("Role_Developer_DebugUser") = True then
        %>
        <h1><font color="red"><% = strTempPassword %></font></h1>
        <%
    End if
    %>
    <span class="MainCopy">A new password has been emailed to you. Please check your email and use the temporary password provided to access your account<br /> via the link provided. &nbsp; You can then choose a new password.</span>
    <%
End if
%>

<!--#include virtual="/Assets/Templates/Public/Franchise/TemplateEnd.asp"-->
</body>
</html>
<!--#include virtual="/System/Shutdown.asp"-->
```

Comment: Showing serverside code for a clientside problem is useless. Show the generated clientside code that the browser sees.

Comment: You should really stop creating SQL commands by concatenating strings and use parameters instead. No matter how clever that CleanSQLText method is, chances are it's a security hole waiting to be exploited.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, it's the Javascript.  You don't have an element with an ID of strUsername.  Add id="strUsername" to the input element you want to focus.

```
<input type="text" id="strUsername" name="strUsername" value="" />
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply, big help that... Should I place the id="strUsername" here:  <input type="text" name="strUsername" value="" />?

Comment: Sorry, that sent a bit quickly!  Excuse my basic help requirement... Should the id be added to the input element for name="strUsername"?  Many thanks for your help

Comment: It should be added to whatever input field you're trying to focus!  But I'm assuming so, yes.  I've edited my response to show this...

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('strUsername').focus();
```

This call is failing because you don't have an element with that **ID** on the page. You need to assign the ID attribute as well as the name attribute:

```
<input type="text" id="strUsername" name="strUsername" value="" />
```

Just like the error message is telling you, it can't find an element by that ID, so that function returns null, and you can't call `focus()` on a null reference.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help, I've done that which removes the Chrome jscript error, however the page is still distorted in IE... Just can't figure it out. Thanks for fixing that though and if there's any other ideas for the distortion it'd be much appreciated...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "distorted". I can see that your top menu last item runs to the next line. Looks like this is due to the width you have defined on your <span> tags inside your menu <a> links.